# How to index a WEB TREC collection?

Tags: lucene, information-retrieval

I've build a WEB TREC collection by downloading and parsing html pages by myself. Each TREC file contains a Category field. How can I build an index by using Lucene in order to perform a search in that collection? The idea is that this search, instead of returning documents as results, it could return categories.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be a relatively simple task since you have them in HTML format. You could index them in Lucene thus (Java based pseudo code)

```
foreach(file in htmlfiles)
{
 Document d = new Document();
 d.add(new Field("Category", GetCategoryName(...), Field.Store.YES,  Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
d.add(new Field("Contents", GetContents(...), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));

writer.addDocument(d);
writer.close();
}
```

GetCategoryName = should return the category string and GetContents(...) the contents of corresponding HTML file.It would be a good idea to parse out the HTML contents from the tags there are several ways of doing it. [HtmlParser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/htmlparser/) being one.

When you search, search the contents field and iterate through your search results to collect your Categories.

If you want to get a list of categories with counts attached ("facets") look into faceted search. Solr is a search server built using Lucene that provides this out of the box.

Comment: So, results won't come ordered by number of hits in the category? I really would like to perform a faceted search. My goal is to, given a query, obtain a weighted list of categories where weights are the number of hits of the query within that category.

Comment: It seems that there're useful methods in lucene. I've found lucene.facets in Contrib directory.